# Get/find javascript object by its parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

Considering I have an array of objects, and all objects represent something out of a database, thus they have an unique identifier.

Now I also have the ID and the correct array. How do I search each object in that array where the parameter 'id' equals my ID. (The point is, I don't know the internal identifier for that object. All I have is an ID and I need the entire object for description, last_user, created etc..)

```
Object
created: "2011-06-08 15:47:11"
description: "Something new.."
id: "1"
last_user: "1"
```

P.s. I have jQuery embedded, so if there's no default way, a jQuery function would suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$.grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) should do it. In the following example `arr` is your array of objects. It will find the element that has an `id` of `1`.

```
var obj = jQuery.grep(arr, function(el, i){
  return el.id == 1;
})[0];
```

Comment: dont you mean `return el.id == 1;` ?

Comment: Nice, thank you. Not sure what the .get(0) is for. It doesn't work for me. I now have this: var refId = this.id;
     var refObj = $.grep(markers[theme], function(el, i){
      return el.id == refId;
     })[0];

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through your array of objects, and check for each one if `yourObject.id` is equal to the `id` you are looking for. Then you'll be able to get the other fields, such as `yourObject.created`